# To prove compactness of some subset

Tags: real-analysis

Question
Show that (0,1] is not compact by constructing an open cover (0,1] that does not have a finite sub over

-> since set is compact if and only if every sub open cover is an finite set
But open cover (0,1] have infinite sub open cover such as (0,1-1/n) n=0 to infinity
So (0,1] is not satisfy the compactness

Is this reasonable proof?

```
oh no i mean (0,1-1/n]
```

Comment: No. $(0,1-1/n)$ is **not** a cover of your set. Consider $(1/n,1]$ instead.

Comment: Even if your sets did cover $(0,1]$, you would still need to show that no finitely many of them cover $(0,1]$.

Answer (score 2):

Try $$(0,1] = \bigcup_{n\ge 1} (1/n, 1].$$

Comment: This works, but there's a somewhat simpler way of putting it.

Answer (score 2):

The set $\{ (a,1] : 0<a\le 1 \}$ is an open cover of $(0,1]$ and there is no finite subcover.

Answer (score 1):

I think some of the existing answers are going to lead to some confusion. Note that if you take $(0,1]$ as a set in and of itself but viewed as a subset of $\mathbb R$, then you are working in the subset topology wherein sets like $(1/n,1]$ are open. However, if you want to view $(0,1]$ as just a subset of $\mathbb R$, then you may take the open sets $(1/n, 1+\epsilon)$ for any positive $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out, $(0,\frac{n-1}{n})$ is not a cover of $(0,1]$. Consider how 1 will be covered this way. You may try the case $(0,1)$ first, and see why finite many covers is not enough in this case. Then $(0,1]$ follows by the same logic.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach: a (subset of) a metric space* is compact if every sequence has a convergent subsequence. Consider the sequence $\{1/n:n=1,2,\ldots\}$. Does this equence have a convergent subsequence?

*With the subspace metric. This is then itself a metric space.